# Why couldn't I convert this integer into a logic_vector?

Tags: vhdl, hardware

I have been trying to convert this Signal of type integer into an std_logic vector and assign the converted value into another signal that has the same width as a VHDL integer

```
signal temp : std_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) := (others => '0'); 
signal FrameCumulative : integer :=0;

temp <= to_stdlogicvector(to_unsigned(FrameCumulative));
```

However I get this error:

> Error (10346): VHDL error at vga.vhd(107): formal port or parameter
>   "SIZE" must have actual or default value

I am using `use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;` and `use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;`

First I made the mistake of not checking the integer size within VHDL and tried to assign an integer into a 14-bit vector but after I gave it some thought I relised my mistake.

Now according to many on-line resources, what I am doing should work but my synthesiser complains about it.

If you do know the cause for this would you mind ellaborating on your answer rather than just posting the correct code, Thanks!

Comment: The declaration of `FrameCumulative` is not given. Your example code declares `AccumelatedFrameVals`. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `to_unsigned` must be provided with a parameter specifying the width of the vector that you want it to produce. The function `to_stdlogicvector` is also not the correct thing to be using. Your line should look like this:

```
temp <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(FrameCumulative, temp'length));
```

The function `to_unsigned` is a conversion function, it must be provided with the target width. Here, as suggested by @BrianDrummond, the width is specified by taking the `length` attribute from the target vector itself (`temp`). The `std_logic_vector` is a type cast, where the `unsigned` value is simply interpreted directly as an `std_logic_vector`.

Comment: Better to use `temp'size` rather than `32`, one less thing to maintain later.

Comment: Thanks that solved it. I should have looked into the functions parameters first! can temp be less 32-bits wide? As I don't intend to use all bits!

Comment: @Aboudi you can convert to whatever width you want, but you of course need to be sure that your expected range of values will fit into this if you want it to work properly.